# Limit of an Integral of Bernstein Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined on $[0,1]$. The Bernstein Polynomial is defined as 
$ B_n (x)=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}f(i/n)x^i (1-x)^{n-i} $. Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 B_n (x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x) dx.$

Answer (score 5):

Using generating functions, we know that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni t^ix^i(1-x)^{n-i}=(1-x+tx)^n
$$
Integration gives
\begin{align}
\int_0^1(1-x+tx)^n\,dx
&=\left[\frac{(1-x+tx)^{n+1}}{(n+1)(t-1)}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}
=\frac{t^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)(t-1)}
\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}(1+t+t^2+...+t^n)
\end{align}
which tells us that individually
$$
\int_0^1\binom ni x^i(1-x)^{n-i}\,dx=\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: (+1) It would probably be easier just to compute the last integral using the beta function and mention Riemann summation.

Comment: Yes, if one is comfortable with the use of the beta function and its integral representations, that would be faster.